# Fitnesse tool for VC++ environment

Tags: visual-c++, testing, automation, fitnesse

I have been told to test a codebase using Fitnesse tool. But the problem is that the code is written in VC++ with MFC and other windows programming things (of which I have no idea at present).

I know how to use Fitnesse tool for java but not for VC++. I read it on their site about some documentation regarding vc++, but was not clear. Also I am working in windows environment and I am not allowed to use Linux. So please if somebody can tell me how to integrate it for VC++, so that I am able do my job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the java fitnesse, but you need a custom "testrunner" implementation.

There is one for [dotNET](http://fitsharp.github.io/), but I am not sure one exists for MFC

Try http://fitnesse.org/PlugIns for a full list

You may be able to port the C++ slim to MFC